# Экранирование специалных символов для аргументов SSH команды

Tags: unix, shell, символы, экранирование

Задача:

1. Переменная, содержит в конце `$$`

   ```
   $ a='SYS_$$'

   $ echo $a

   SYS_$$
   ```
2. Тут разворачивает `$$` в конце строки как номер процесса, а надо отобразить строку `"SYS_$$"`, передаваемую как параметр.

   ```
   $ echo "echo \$1" | ssh another_host "/bin/sh -s $a"

   SYS_18992
   ```

Comment: используйте одинарные кавычки для echo

Comment: Одинарные кавычки не помогли:

my_host: $ echo 'echo \$1' | ssh another_host "/bin/sh -s $a"

$1


my_host:rman: $ echo 'echo $1' | ssh another_host "/bin/sh -s $a"

SYS_26315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$ a='SYS_$$'
$ echo 'echo $1' | ssh another_host "/bin/sh -s '$a'"

SYS_$$
```

- При вызове `ssh`, внутри двойных кавычек одиночные кавычки тетряют своё специальное назначение и переменная `$а` будет замещена её значением, т.е. `$SYS_$$`.
- Далее, при вызове `sh` на удалённом хосте, одиночные кавычки вновь приобретают своё специальное назначение и препятствуют замещению `$$` текущим `pid`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло! То что надо!

Comment: Нет, все-таки не помогло:

my_host: $ a=SYS_$$$

my_host: $ echo 'echo $1' | ssh another_host "/bin/sh -s '$a' "

SYS_8847608$

Comment: Здесь - a=SYS_$$$ - куда кавычки пропали?

Comment: да, точно, я ошибся.. работает

Comment: Хорошо, не забудте отметить ответ Баракина как принятый.

Answer (score 4):

надо **передать** символы одинарных кавычек вокруг аргумента, с которым вызывается программа *sh*. для этого надо добавить перед кавычками символы `\`:

```
$ v='a$$'; echo 'echo $1' | ssh хост sh -s \'$v\'
a$$
```